# how to debug and issue tracking ios ui freezing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, freeze

I am developing a live platform using amazon IVS player SDK.
But I have a little problem.

The ui freezing phenomenon occurs intermittently, but it is difficult to debug because the clear call stack is not visible.

I have doubts, but I can't see it as open source.

[mainThread callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y5V4.jpg)
[Suspicious thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HY6y.jpg)

The situation is as follows, but my expectation is that "psync_mutexwait" occurs on the "AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer" side on the open source side and freezes.. I am not sure if this is correct.

So, I'm going to do more debugging, but if there is any reason to think about it or any tips for debugging when the call stack is as follows in the state of ui freezing,
Please let me know that knowledge.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use XCode profiler. Go to `Product > Profile` and select Game Performance. It should help you to detect UI freezes at runtime. Detailed guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_metal_system_trace_in_instruments_to_profile_your_app).